# Can a class be resolved using Castle Windsor from a string

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, instantiation

I have different Processor objects that implement IProcessor and I need to instantiate/resolve a processor within a method based on a string value that’s passed in. Something like:

```
var myClass = "Project.Processors.FastProcessor";
MyMethod(myClass);

Public void MyMethod(string myClass)
{
 var processor = container.Resolve< myClass >();
}
```

Is this achievable with castle windsor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var processor = container.Resolve(Type.GetType(myClass));
```